# Condition that should change configuration of a cell is not working, probably because of how the feed is populated

Tags: swift, uicollectionview

I am using XCode 9, and I have created a collection view programmatically. I have a function called populateFeedCollectionViewCell, where I use the data I have gotten from the server to populate each cell of my collection view. I call this fuction at cell for item.

In my populateFeedCollectionViewCell function I check if the Item has an image of not, and when it doesn't have an image, I tell the image view to be frame 1,1, by altering its constraints.

For some reason, this isn't working properly. All the items that should be altered are being altered with success, but other items are being altered as well (just some of them).

I make the xcode print me the item when it enters the condition where I alter the constraints, and the weird thing is that the items arent being printed (therefore aren't entering the condition by mistake), but are changing its constraints.

My guess is that when the override cell for item is being called, it is mistaking the index or something. But I don't know how to be sure that that is the problem nor how to fix it.

Here is my code:

Where I call populateFeedCollectionViewCell

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath) as! CustomFeedCell
    presenter.populateFeedCollectionViewCell(cell: cell, item: itemArray[indexPath.row])
    cell.shareButton.tag = indexPath.row
    cell.delateButton.tag = indexPath.row
    return cell
}
```

Where I give the condition, inside populateFeedCollectionViewCell:

```
    if item.mediaUrl == "empty"{
        debugPrint("entrou em empty", "media url:", item.mediaUrl, "title:", item.title)
        cell.feedImageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 206.0).isActive = false
        cell.feedImageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 341.0).isActive = false
        cell.feedImageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 1).isActive = true
        cell.feedImageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 1).isActive = true

    } else {
        cell.feedImageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 1).isActive = false
        cell.feedImageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 1).isActive = false
        cell.feedImageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 206.0).isActive = true
        cell.feedImageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 341.0).isActive = true
    }
```

The result on my feed:
ps: notice that when it doesnt have an image it is correct, but when you see the image as a line on top of the text, the constraints were applied when they shouldnt have been. Also, when I scroll the feed, other items change their constraints to the wrong way.

[Image 1 (constraints applied correctly)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aUiWV.png)

[Image 2 (constraints applied when shouldn't be)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IVed3.png)

[Image 3 (constraints not when shouldn't be)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h1vYo.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since there is cell resuing inside `cellForItemAt` , every time the cell reused it creates other constraints which conflicts , then cause unexpected results , you need to clear all constraints of `feedImageView` before creating new ones

Or better to create the constraints inside xib/custom class , then hook them as outlets and play with there constants

```
if item.mediaUrl == "empty"{       
    cell.feedImageViewWidth.constant = 1.0
    cell.feedImageViewheight.constant = 1.0
} else {
    cell.feedImageViewWidth.constant = 341.0
    cell.feedImageViewheight.constant = 206.0
}
```

where

```
var feedImageViewWidth:NSLayoutConstraint! // or @IBOulet weak var .....
var feedImageViewheight:NSLayoutConstraint!
```

> Warning:
>
> Don't think constraints with
>
> .isActive = false
>
> deactivates old ones , No they add another deactivated constraint

Comment: Thank you, I am not using xib, so I fixed the problem by setting the condition where I first give the constraints to cell, instead of replacing them and it seems to be working!  And thanks for the warning! That clarifies a lot :D